# How to make procfile for java server on heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, server, xmpp, procfile

I spent a day trying to run a java xmpp fcm server for Google Firebase messaging.
Following that [example](https://github.com/carlosCharz/fcmxmppserverv2) to establish the server on Heroku service, I figured out that I need to create procfile file. 
[Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) is:

> A Procfile is a mechanism for declaring what commands are run by your
>   application’s dynos on the Heroku platform.

Until now I tried to start it with commands like:

```
web: java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.wedevol.xmpp.server.CcsClient
```

But it's not working.
$ heroku logs:

```
2017-01-31T13:14:50.844896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-forest-64025.herokuapp.com request_id=a8a8b191-3679-4746-abf3-c7766fbb8764 fwd="141.226.161.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

$ heroku ps returns:

```
=== web (Free): java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.wedevol.xmpp.server.CcsClient (1) web.1: crashed 2017/01/31 15:13:08 +0200 (~ 5m ago)
```

Here I need your help. What I need to define in that file to run successfully a Java server (from link above). 
Thanks!

**For additional information, the original POM file is looked like that:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.wedevol</groupId>
<artifactId>xmppserver2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>FCM XMPP Server</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-java7</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>xmpp-server</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Set a JDK compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Your question is very broad. It is best to be more specific, to show the code you have tried.

Comment: @AlLelopath edited my question, hope now it's more specific and clear. Have you some idea about my issue? Thanks.

Comment: How do you run the application locally (what command do you use to run it)? Also, can you elaborate on "it's not working"? Do you see an error in `heroku logs`?

Comment: @codefinger edited and added logs and another information. It seems that server app crashes but I don't know why. Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours of pain finally got the right Procfile for that Java server:

```
web: java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.wedevol.xmpp.EntryPoint
```

*Don't forget to build the project before upload with:

```
mvn package
```